# Generate Yes/No in RTF reports instread of True/False

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to generate string Yes/No instead of True/False in Enterprise Architect RTF Reports.

I can achieve it by writing custom script, but in tah case i have to generate all report data. This is quite expensive.
I thought I can use Word substitution, but I'm not able to add new word substitution pair.

Is there a way how to replace True/False by Yes/No?

I am using EA version 12.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't found a way either. So I'm using a script fragment or an SQL Fragment in these cases.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this conversion at attribute property (Null/not null). So I have to implement whole attribute set template using script fragment. At the moment I do substitution using Word macros. Thank you for answer!